What should I do if I don't understand the problem my PhD project is meant to solve?
I have been struggling to understand what problem my PhD project is trying to solve. The project did not start with a problem. Instead, the project started with tasks assigned to me by the PI. But the tasks are not in logical order. The project is mostly the PI's ideas. I don't have a say. Please, what should I do in this situation?

Your question never spells out how the problem was actually defined. Did your PI assign it to you explicitly? Did you infer it from the tasks? Are you sure there actually is already a specific problem? Many PhDs are months of "standard" tasks meant to give you an understanding of the field and along the way find a problem to focus on.

The problem was never defined to me. The tasks are not meant to find a problem.

Go to your PI immediately and discuss with them until you are sufficiently happy. That certainly does not mean you need to need to understand everything 100%, but you should at least be satisfied that you understand the context well enough. If there was a project proposal involved at some point to get grant money for the project, ask for that - that typically has all the information, and while it was already written with a subject matter expert audience in mind, it would still be invaluable to you.
In a Ph.D. project, you are not a technician or factory worker who does their assigned task with little visibility to the greater whole. You are training to be an academic. This is your apprenticeship to be qualified to lead similar projects yourself in the future, whether in academia or outside. This period is absolutely the point where you need to look beyond the technical tasks of the moment.

A worker is exactly how I feel, not a student. But discussing this with the PI previously has not led to me becoming sufficiently happy. The PI doesn't see the importance of explaining.

Then your problem is with your supervisor. I would recommend you take a look at our questions in the [tag:supervision] tag, potentially edit your question to include information about your interaction so far to the supervisor, and more information about your situation.

This is true, but different countries can have different perspectives: in some places PhD students are hired directly by the PI with their own funds and for a specific task, so it's understandable it would end up feeling like that in some cases. Nonetheless, do follow Stephan's advice because a PhD definitely needs structure and focus
